# How to make div update with zoom level?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html

I have a div that updates with mousehover. For example, when you hover over GA it displays the data for GA, when you hover over NC, it displays the data for NC, etc. I want to have the same div, but have it update county-level data once the state is clicked and zoomed in on. Basically, zoom out and have the div update state data, zoom in and have it update county data.

would I add `Info1` div code somewhere in the event listener below?

```
// Event Listener
    map.on("zoomend", (x) => {
      if (stateZoomLevel < map.getZoom()) {
        showCountiesHideStates();
      }
    });
```

Here's the rest of the code.

```
    var map = L.map("map", {
    center: [39.5, -95.3],
    zoom: 3.5,
  });

  (async () => {
    let stateZoomLevel;

    // add basemap
    var Stamen_TonerLite = L.tileLayer(
      "https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png",
      {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a> | <a href="https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-County/8xkx-amqh/data">County data</a> | <a href="https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-Jurisdi/unsk-b7fc/data">State data</a> | Map: <a href="https://weircf.wixsite.com/e-portfolio">Chip Weir</a>',
        subdomains: "abcd",
        maxZoom: 19,
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    var infoStates = L.control();
    infoStates.onAdd = function (map) {
      this._div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info"); // create a div with a class "info"
      this.update();
      return this._div;
    };

    // method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
    infoStates.update = function (props) {
      this._div.innerHTML = props
        ? "<b>" +
          props.name +
          "</b><br /><b>" +
          props.vaxData_states_Series_Complete_Pop_Pct +
          "</b>" +
          " of the population is fully vaccinated" +
          "<br />" +
          "<h6>" +
          "As of " +
          props.vaxData_states_Date +
          "</h6>" +
          "<h6>" +
          "The CDC's definition of fully vaccinated: Someone who has recieved the second dose of a two-dose vaccine or one dose a of single-dose vaccine" +
          "</h6>"
        : "Hover over a state and click for county data";
    };
    infoStates.addTo(map);

    var infoCounties = L.control();
    infoCounties.onAdd = function (map) {
      this._div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info1"); // create a div with a class "info"
      this.update();
      return this._div;
    };

    // method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
    infoCounties.update = function (props) {
      this._div.innerHTML = props
        ? "<b>" +
          props.NAMELSAD +
          ", " +
          props.STUSPS +
          "</b><br /><b>" +
          props.vaxData_Series_Complete_Pop_Pct +
          "</b>" +
          " of the population is fully vaccinated" +
          "<br />" +
          "<h6>" +
          "As of " +
          props.vaxData_Date +
          "</h6>" +
          "<h6>" +
          "The CDC's definition of fully vaccinated: Someone who has recieved the second dose of a two-dose vaccine or one dose a of single-dose vaccine" +
          "</h6>"
        : "Hover over a county";
    };
    infoCounties.addTo(map);

    //zoom to a state, turn off state data, turn on county data
    function zoomToFeature(e) {
      map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
      showCountiesHideStates(e.target.feature.properties.STATE);
      map.addLayer(stateborders);
      // Save current Zoom Level
      stateZoomLevel = map.getBoundsZoom(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    //zoom to county
    function zoomToFeature1(e) {
      map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    // Event Listener
    map.on("zoomend", (x) => {
      if (stateZoomLevel > map.getZoom()) {
        showStatesHideCounties();
      }
    });

    // Event Listener
    map.on("zoomend", (x) => {
      if (stateZoomLevel < map.getZoom()) {
        showCountiesHideStates();
      }
    });

    function highlightFeature(e) {
      var layer = e.target;
      layer.setStyle({
        weight: 4,
        opacity: 1,
        color: "#dbff4d",
      });
      layer.bringToFront();
      infoStates.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

    function highlightFeature1(e) {
      var layer = e.target;
      layer.setStyle({
        weight: 4,
        opacity: 1,
        color: "#dbff4d",
      });
      layer.bringToFront();
      infoCounties.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

    //reset the hightlighted states on mouseout
    function resetHighlight(e) {
      geojsonStates.resetStyle(e.target);
      infoStates.update();
    }

    //reset the hightlighted counties on mouseout
    function resetHighlight1(e) {
      geojsonCounties.resetStyle(e.target);
      infoCounties.update();
    }

    //add these events to the layer object
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        click: zoomToFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
      });
    }

    //add these events to the layer object
    function onEachFeature1(feature, layer) {
      layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature1,
        click: zoomToFeature1,
        mouseout: resetHighlight1,
      });
    }

    function getColor(d) {
      return d > 70
        ? "#1a9641"
        : d >= 60
        ? "#a6d96a"
        : d >= 50
        ? "#fdae61"
        : d < 50
        ? "#d7191c"
        : "#5f5f5f";
    }

    function getColor1(d) {
      return d >= 75
        ? "#1a9641"
        : d >= 50
        ? "#a6d96a"
        : d >= 25
        ? "#fdae61"
        : d > 0
        ? "#d7191c"
        : "#5f5f5f";
    }

    function states(feature) {
      return {
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: "whitesmoke",
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.vaxData_states_Series_Complete),
      };
    }

    function counties(feature) {
      return {
        weight: 0.5,
        opacity: 0.5,
        color: "whitesmoke",
        fillOpacity: 0.75,
        fillColor: getColor1(feature.properties.vaxData_Series_Complete),
      };
    }

    function borders(feature) {
      return {
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 1,
        zindex: 1000,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        interactive: false,
        color: "whitesmoke",
      };
    }

    // add state borders
    const geojsonStatesData = await fetch("data/us_states.geojson").then((r) =>
      r.json()
    );
    var geojsonStates = L.geoJson(geojsonStatesData, {
      style: states,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    });

    geojsonStates.addTo(map);

    //add county geojson
    const geojsonCountiesData = await fetch("data/counties.geojson").then((r) =>
      r.json()
    );
    var geojsonCounties = L.geoJson(geojsonCountiesData, {
      style: counties,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature1,
    });

    geojsonCounties.addTo(map);

    // add state borders
    var stateborders = L.geoJson.ajax("data/us_states.geojson", {
      style: borders,
    });

    function showStatesHideCounties() {
      geojsonStates.show();
      geojsonCounties.hide();
    }

    function showCountiesHideStates(stateId) {
      if (stateId) {
        geojsonCounties.show((layer) => {
          return layer.feature.properties.STATE === stateId;
        });
      } else {
        geojsonCounties.show();
      }
      geojsonStates.hide();
    }

    // Init
    showStatesHideCounties();
  })();
```

Comment: And how does it behave now? What goes wrong?

Comment: @TomazicM currently the county info div shows up on top of the state info div. I would like for them to up at the same spot on the screen like that BUT at different zoom levels essentially.